# Does web.config guarantee 100% protection?

Tags: drupal-7, web-config

I need to set up a secure website to transfer data between 5 computers located in different states. The data is sensitive.

I am planning to use drupal. However, I read many articles about drupal 7 getting hacked . So I want to restrict website access using web.config . As far as I understand nobody can even try to hack the website because it will be not accessible from any IP not listed in the web.config Does this guarantee 100% protection ?

```
<security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
        <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
        <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>    <!-- allow requests from the local machine -->
        <add ipAddress="83.xxx.xx.53" allowed="true"/>   <!-- allow the specific IP of 83.116.19.53  -->                
        <add ipAddress="83.xxx.xx.0" subnetMask="xxx.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>   <!--allow network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->                
        <add ipAddress="83.xxx.0.0" subnetMask="2xx55.255.0.0" allowed="true"/>   <!--allow network 83.116.0.0 to 83.116.255.255-->                
        <add ipAddress="83.xxxx.0.0" subnetMask="255.0.0.0" allowed="true"/>   <!--allow entire /8 network of 83.0.0.0 to 83.xxx.255.255-->                
    </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: of course it does not.

Comment: By posting your actual IP addresses in the question, you have told the world there is *something* highly sensitive at those addresses.  I suggest you edit your question to use made-up IP addresses and flag for moderation, requesting that the edit history be deleted due to containing sensitive information.

Comment: You would have to read every piece of code that goes into your sites, to assure that you don't have hacked code on your site in the first place, if you're using Drupal.

Comment: This is a reasonable question for someone new to security.  The `<security>` feature is offered, so one might think (incorrectly) that it may provide adequate security.  Much better to have asked than to just assume it's there so it must provide adequate protection.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your web server is exposed to the Internet, it is vulnerable to hacking attempts.  There could be a flaw, current or future, that allows the hacker to bypass application level IP restrictions.

You should explicitly deny access for most IP addresses to the web server (typically Port 80 for HTTP, and Port 443 for HTTPS... which I'm sure you are using as your website deals with secure data).  Explicitly allow access only for the IPs you have listed.